# Replacing Retro Plumbing

Tags: plumbing

Thought it was going to be a straight forward replacement of bathroom sink p-trap. But while I was able to loosen the slip-nut joint between tailpiece and u-bend, the other end of u-bend doesn't have a nut and is a solid piece that's glued to the drain pipe. How is this removed or replaced?[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Do you have a better (larger) picture of the problem? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: A picture of the complete P-trap showing both ends

Comment: Is there any way you could post a smaller picture?